# How can I tell the version of a package which will be installed before I install it?

Tags: apt

I can add a `ppa` which would change the version of a package in the repositories - for example Inkscape has a dev version.

Before I install "Inkscape" with `sudo apt-get install inkscape`, how can I know which version will be installed?

Comment: May be your question is same as [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6284/check-package-version-using-apt-get-aptitude).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `apt-cache policy`:

```
$ apt-cache policy gitlab-ce
gitlab-ce:
  Installed: 8.6.1-ce.0
  Candidate: 8.7.0-ce.0
  Version table:
     8.7.0-ce.0 0
        500 https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ce/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
     8.6.7-ce.0 0
        500 https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ce/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
     8.6.6-ce.0 0
        500 https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ce/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
     8.6.5-ce.0 0
        500 https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ce/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
     8.6.4-ce.0 0
        500 https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ce/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
     8.6.3-ce.0 0
        500 https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ce/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
     8.6.2-ce.0 0
        500 https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ce/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
 *** 8.6.1-ce.0 0
        500 https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ce/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     8.6.0-ce.0 0
        500 https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ce/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
     8.5.11-ce.1 0
        500 https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ce/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
     8.5.10-ce.0 0
        500 https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ce/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

The version listed as the `Candidate` will be picked. The current version (if any) will be listed as `Installed` and marked with the asterisks.

Comment: Probably a better example would be one with multiple versions available (e.g. debootstrap or clang-3.8 in Ubuntu 16.04 now).